# Existence of a finite group union of self normalizing subgroups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Does a finite group G union of self normalizing subgroups such that the intersection of any two of these subgroups is equal to the unit of group G exist?
I don't think so, but I can't prove it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Perhaps "Does" = "Can", and "$\;G\;$ union" = "$\;G\;$ be the union" ? And by "self normalizing", you mean a subgroup $\;H\;$ such that $\;H=N_G(H)\;$ ?

Comment: Yes, it's what I mean.

Comment: follow-up and answered at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/180077/existence-of-a-finite-group-which-is-the-union-of-self-normalizing-subgroups